# Onsen-ui Carousel properties auto play not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, onsen-ui

I am using onsen UI here I use carousel in my mobile web app, but here some problem occurs by which I am unable to use the property autoplay.

```
   <ons-page>
     <ons-toolbar>
     <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button onclick="prev()">
        <ons-icon icon="md-chevron-left"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
     </div>
     <div class="center">Carousel</div>
     <div class="right">
      <ons-toolbar-button onclick="next()">
        <ons-icon icon="md-chevron-right"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      </ons-toolbar>

     <ons-carousel fullscreen auto-scroll id="carousel">
     <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #085078;">
        <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 
       20px; 
      color: #fff;">
        BLUE
      </div>
      </ons-carousel-item>
      <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #373B44;">
      <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 20px; 
      color: #fff;">
        DARK
      </div>
       </ons-carousel-item>
       <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #D38312;">
      <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 20px; 
         color: #fff;">
        ORANGE
        </div>
        </ons-carousel-item>
       < /ons-carousel>  
       </ons-page>
```

And My Javascript:

```
var prev = function() {
       var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
       carousel.prev();
};

var next = function() {
       var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
       carousel.next();
};

ons.ready(function() {
       var carousel = document.addEventListener('postchange', function(event) {
       console.log('Changed to ' + event.activeIndex)
  });
});
```

No error msg occurs but my autoplay option is not working.

Comment: Do you mean `auto-scroll` option by saying "autoplay"?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `auto-scroll` option by saying "autoplay" I suppose you misunderstand the goal of `auto-scroll` option and expect that the carousel will go through its items without any user's action with `auto-scroll` option.

From the [documentation](https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-carousel.html#attributes):

> auto-scroll: If this attribute is set the carousel will be automatically scrolled to the closest item border when released.

See how it works in the [playground](https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-carousel.html#tutorial). With `auto-scroll` option when a user wants to swipe to the next or previous item in the carousel she doesn't need to swipe until the end. It's enough to swipe partially because then the carousel will finish swiping automatically. Delete `auto-scroll` option, press Run and try to swipe the carousel. You will see that swiping stops where you released.

So, `auto-scroll` is not autoplay. But how to implement autoplay after all? Just use carousel methods (`next`, `first` and `getActiveIndex`) and properties (`itemCount`) in `setInterval` function.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
  if (carousel.getActiveIndex() === carousel.itemCount-1)
     carousel.first();
  else
     carousel.next(); 
}, 1000);
```

```js
var prev = function() {
       var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
       carousel.prev();
};

var next = function() {
       var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
       carousel.next();
};

ons.ready(function() {
       var carousel = document.addEventListener('postchange', function(event) {
       console.log('Changed to ' + event.activeIndex)
  });
});

setInterval(function(){ 
  var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
  if (carousel.getActiveIndex() === carousel.itemCount-1)
     carousel.first();
  else
     carousel.next(); 
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/onsenui/js/onsenui.js"></script>
  <ons-page>
     <ons-toolbar>
     <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button onclick="prev()">
        <ons-icon icon="md-chevron-left"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
     </div>
     <div class="center">Carousel</div>
     <div class="right">
      <ons-toolbar-button onclick="next()">
        <ons-icon icon="md-chevron-right"></ons-icon>
      </ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      </ons-toolbar>

     <ons-carousel fullscreen id="carousel">
     <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #085078;">
        <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 
       20px; 
      color: #fff;">
        BLUE
      </div>
      </ons-carousel-item>
      <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #373B44;">
      <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 20px; 
      color: #fff;">
        DARK
      </div>
       </ons-carousel-item>
       <ons-carousel-item style="background-color: #D38312;">
      <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 30px; margin-top: 20px; 
         color: #fff;">
        ORANGE
        </div>
        </ons-carousel-item>
       < /ons-carousel>  
       </ons-page>
```

Comment: but when we include the auto-scroll method on only HTML element then it is not working which is predefined by onsen ( https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-carousel.html#attributes), we need to write javascript code for it.

Comment: `auto-scroll` works without javascript. But it doesn't work without `swipeable` attribute

Comment: It's not the problem. `auto-scroll` doesn't make sense without `swipeable`. I wrote `setInterval` not for making `auto-scroll` work. `Auto-scroll` attribute is for completely different task than autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

This function perfectly works for me ...

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
  if (carousel.getActiveIndex() === carousel.itemCount-1)
     carousel.first();
  else
     carousel.next(); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: The code in this answer is identical to that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58235818/1364007).